# I want to find the sum of the number which i have

Tags: python

I have some code where I must find the multiples of number 3 and then summarize them 
I have done the first job, I mean I found all the multiples of number 3 with for loop but I can't summarize all the numbers which I found.

I have tried so many times and tried to find the solution on google, but could not find

```
x = 3
for number in range(1000):
    if number%x == 0:
        print(number)
```

I need now the sum of all the numbers which indicates on this code, when you run this code you can see that there is publishing only the numbers that can divide by 3 now I need the sum of them

Comment: Create a new variable and add `number` to it whenever the condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 10):

It's easier than you think:

```
sum(range(0, 1000, 3))
```

Explanation:

`range` is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) as such: `range([start], end[, step])` so `range(0, 1000, 3)` means go from 0 to 1000 in steps of 3

The `sum` function will sum over any iterable (which includes range)

Answer (score 4):

You need a variable to hold the sum (If you are in learning stage):

```
x = 3
total = 0
for number in range(1000):
    if number % x == 0:
        print(number)
        total += number # equivalent to:  total = total + number
print(total)
```

Edit:
To answer your comment use `condition or condition`:

```
x = 3
y = 5
total = 0
for number in range(10):
    if number % x == 0 or number % y == 0:
        print(number)
        total += number # equivalent to:  total = total + number
print(total)
```

Comment: thank you  but i have tried to make this code
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.|| i cant find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `result` variable to which you can keep adding:

```py
result = 0
x = 3
for number in range(1000):
    if number%x == 0:
        result += number
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using `filter` and `sum`:

```
# any iterable variable
iterable_var = range(100)
res = sum(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, iterable_var), 0)
```